# A command for pasting; the same as Ctrl + V

Tags: command-line, kubuntu

Is there a command for pasting what is in clipboard?
I need a command that does the same thing as to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

I tried a few options for `xclip`, but they don't paste normally and need middle click or so.

Comment: Your question above and your comment in reply to @konapun's anwser seem to contradict each other. Apart from that the answer to your **question** would be `xsel -o -b` (for pasting the 'normal' clipboard to standard out, as via Ctrl+V) or `xsel -o` (for the X clipboard, which you could also paste via a middle-click of the mouse).

Comment: xsel -o -b does not work outside a terminal.

Comment: Then I'm afraid I still don't understand your question ... why can't you use Ctrl+V itself?

Comment: because I'll use a command to do it. commands do not have hands to type. btw, this question is obsolete for me. I wanted to set a hotkey which copies date and time and then pastes it immediately. Now it's implemented somehow:  Cha, 93/05/15, 15:34:14 (local time). Now it works without bothering clipboard.  Cha, 93/05/15, 15:36:49

Comment: Glad you found a solution. With a 'command' I guess you mean a shell script? For other people having the same question: `date | xclip && xclip -o`.

Comment: yes shell script or something to be fed in a Run Window. But for date I suggest: `xdotool type " $(date) "`. It may also need a command to change keyboard layout to English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Klipper**

The Kubuntu is using as default the Klipper. KDE UserBase: http://userbase.kde.org/Klipper

As a KDE/Qt application the Klipper can be used via the qdbus: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/qdbus.1.html

Available commands can be viewed with the qdbusviewer:

[image]

or with the terminal (konsole):

```
:~$ qdbus org.kde.klipper /klipper
method void org.kde.klipper.klipper.clearClipboardContents()
method void org.kde.klipper.klipper.clearClipboardHistory()
method QString org.kde.klipper.klipper.getClipboardContents()
method QString org.kde.klipper.klipper.getClipboardHistoryItem(int i)
method QStringList org.kde.klipper.klipper.getClipboardHistoryMenu()
method void org.kde.klipper.klipper.saveClipboardHistory()
method void org.kde.klipper.klipper.setClipboardContents(QString s)
method void org.kde.klipper.klipper.showKlipperManuallyInvokeActionMenu()
method void org.kde.klipper.klipper.showKlipperPopupMenu()
method QDBusVariant org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get(QString interface_name, QString property_name)
method QVariantMap org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.GetAll(QString interface_name)
method void org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Set(QString interface_name, QString property_name, QDBusVariant value)
method QString org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable.Introspect()
method QString org.freedesktop.DBus.Peer.GetMachineId()
method void org.freedesktop.DBus.Peer.Ping()
```

The command

```
qdbus org.kde.klipper /klipper getClipboardContents
```

will get the last line from the clipboard.

The command can added to the KDE menu (http://docs.kde.org/development/en/kde-workspace/kmenuedit/index.html) and called with the keyboard shortcut or to the file manager context menu (KDE service menu - http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Creating_Konqueror_Service_Menus).

[image]

Other options for the clipboard managers: http://qt-apps.org/content/show.php/CopyQ?content=147452

Comment: `qdbus org.kde.klipper /klipper getClipboardContents` gives an error for me: `qdbus: could not exec '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qdbus': No such file or directory` something is missing!

Comment: As default the KDE 4 is using the Qt 4. Sometimes the upgrade will mess the things: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1175251

Answer (score 0):

Yes, install the package `xsel`

`xsel --clipboard` will paste the clipboard contents.

Comment: You might want to add that you can install it from [here](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xsel/), and that you can also use `xsel -b` ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately this command just prints the clipboard content in terminal. Outside it, it does not work. I want to assign a hotkey to run such a command (along with other ones) to work the same as Ctrl+V.

Comment: Where are you wanting it to paste? A nonactive window?

Comment: @konapun: everywhere an editing area is focused. for example in this comment. I need a command that will be run without any terminal window open using a hotkey.

Comment: Are you looking for something more like a macro recorder/player? If so, you may want to check out [autokey](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/autokey-gtk/)

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal and type as

```
nano .bashrc
```

then

paste a line as

```
xclip="xclip -selection c"
```

then save & close with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> .

Then type `bash`

then on wards you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste.

Comment: I could use ctrl+v for pasting already! btw, thanks.