# A command for showing desktop

Tags: command-line, kde, plasma

`wmctrl -s` can be used to switch between virtual desktops. Is there a command that shows the desktop? that is a command that will switch between minimizing all windows and restoring them?

Comment: I don't think so. I want a command that does it without sending key combinations artificially. Because that depends on the key combination which may be different or not set in KDE environment (not unity as tagged there). such a command may work in every environment (=why I did not mention explicitly KDE environment). But for me KDE is enough.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus: have you checked the other answers on that question?

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini: Note two answers there are added after my question. Still answers here are richer. And note this question is about plasma and not unity. btw, this question is now done with. no matter closed or open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show the desktop the command:

```
wmctrl -k on
```

To turn it off use

```
wmctrl -k off
```

Comment: btw, `on` and `off` dashes the hope of simulating KDE show desktop widget which has a toggling nature.

Comment: strangely, if you execute the command in yakuake then show yakuake all windows are restored...

Comment: couldn't you just use an if else statement to toggle?

Comment: well I intend to attach a hotkey to it which will run the command. So there will be no terminal. About if statement, I'm not sure how to check the condition. well I may write a C++ code which will save the status in a file and on re-execution will read the file to check the status. Not worth the candle.

Answer (score 2):

This is an adaptation of [virtualxtc](https://askubuntu.com/users/171245/virtualxtc)'s [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/399270/176889) with support for toggling.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

current_mode="$(wmctrl -m | grep 'showing the desktop')"

if [[ "${current_mode##* }" == ON ]]; then
    wmctrl -k off
else
    wmctrl -k on
fi
```

To use, save the above into a file, then mark it executable.

---

#### Explanation of above code

```bash
#!/bin/bash
```

This is a shebang comment.

```bash
current_mode="$(wmctrl -m | grep 'showing the desktop')"
```

This captures the output of `wmctrl -m` piped through `grep 'showing the desktop'` into the variable `$current_mode`.

```bash
if [[ "${current_mode##* }" == ON ]]; then
    wmctrl -k off
else
    wmctrl -k on
fi
```

An `if...else...` statement in Bash. `${current_mode##* }` returns `$current_mode` with the longest match of anything up until a space deleted from the front of the string. If this returns `ON`, turns desktop off; else turns desktop on.

Comment: I tested it but it always minimizes, and does not restore. Maybe `wmctrl -k off` is not working well or `[[ "$current_mode" == ON ]]` is incompatible with it.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus The issue might be that it isn't being run with Bash and is instead run with `sh`. See my edits.

Comment: @minerz029   sweet! can you point me to an explanation of the  ##* part?  I'm assuming it causes it to read the last work after the grepped line or something....

Comment: @virtualxtc The `${var##exp}` returns `$var` with the *longest* match of `exp` deleted from the front of it, where `exp` is a shell glob. `$var` is not actually modified. See [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion) for more details and other similar constructs.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't recognize that the space inside the bracket is nessesary until I reviewed the examples in your link.